# My UITapGestureRecognizer affects all elements in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to do my first ever App, and i'm need to add UITapGestureRecognizer that will scale photo in TableViewCell.

And it is works, but not correctly — my Gesture scale not just photo in ViewCell but all elements in ViewCell. How could I fix this?

All my code for TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "PhotosCollectionViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
    
    var isInScale: Bool = false
        
    func configure(photo: PhotosInProfile) {
        mainPhoto.image = UIImage(named: photo.mainPhoto)
        mainLabel.text = "Date: \(photo.date)"
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageDoubleTapped))
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        mainPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        mainPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }
    
    @objc func imageDoubleTapped() {
        if isInScale {
            self.transform = .identity
        } else {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        }
        isInScale.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `self.transform`, `self` is a `PhotosCollectionViewCell` instance. Did you meant `mainPhoto.transform` instead?

Comment: @Larme oh, you are right. i changed `self` to `mainPhoto` here and it's worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import UIKit

class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
static let identifier = "PhotosCollectionViewCell"

@IBOutlet weak var mainPhoto: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!

var isInScale: Bool = false
    
func configure(photo: PhotosInProfile) {
    mainPhoto.image = UIImage(named: photo.mainPhoto)
    mainLabel.text = "Date: \(photo.date)"
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageDoubleTapped))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    mainPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mainPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}

@objc func imageDoubleTapped() {
    if isInScale {
        mainPhoto.transform = .identity
    } else {
        mainPhoto.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }
    isInScale.toggle()
}
```

}